# Postgres paste table to Local not working

Tags: django, postgresql, navicat

I'm new in Postgres and currently having a trouble on how can I copy past the table through creating new connection in Navicat from a friend. So I just want to paste those table into my local but the problem is I have been encountered this error. I'm been using navicat version 15 and postgres version 11. It is possible that the problem is comes from the table restricted from my friend? Thanks in advance

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHSDo.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Hyp.png)

```
auth_group_id_seq does not exist
```

Comment: Friend or no friend, I guess is irrelevant :-). Your question is about how to migrate data (and structure) from one database engine to another. The way to achieve it is to export the data (and structure) and re-import it. Or to create the structure in both and import/export the data.

Comment: @azbarcea The problem is I can't re import and even dump data due to restriction of the datas , I think this is because of the built in database in Django